# Elastic search query does not fetch results intermittently

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, lucene

When I create index and search for it immediately, I am not getting the results back intermittently. However, in response it says index created. Does elastic search take some time to make the indexes searchable?

```
package in.blogspot.randomcompiler.elastic_search_demo;

import in.blogspot.randomcompiler.elastic_search_impl.Event;

import java.util.Date;

import org.elasticsearch.action.count.CountRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.count.CountResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilterBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.FilterBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchAllFilterBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHits;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class ElasticSearchDemo
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));

        DeleteResponse deleteResponse1 = client.prepareDelete("chat-data", "event", "1").execute().actionGet();
        DeleteResponse deleteResponse2 = client.prepareDelete("chat-data", "event", "2").execute().actionGet();
        DeleteResponse deleteResponse3 = client.prepareDelete("chat-data", "event", "3").execute().actionGet();

        Event e1 = new Event("LOGIN", new Date(), "Agent1 logged into chat");
        String e1Json = e1.prepareJson();        
        System.out.println("JSON: " + e1Json);        
        IndexResponse indexResponse1 = client.prepareIndex("chat-data", "event", "1").setSource(e1Json).execute().actionGet();
        printIndexResponse("e1", indexResponse1);

        Event e2 = new Event("LOGOUT", new Date(), "Agent1 logged out of chat");
        String e2Json = e2.prepareJson();        
        System.out.println("JSON: " + e2Json);        
        IndexResponse indexResponse2 = client.prepareIndex("chat-data", "event", "2").setSource(e2Json).execute().actionGet();
        printIndexResponse("e2", indexResponse2);

        Event e3 = new Event("BREAK", new Date(), "Agent1 went on break in the middle of a chat");
        String e3Json = e3.prepareJson();        
        System.out.println("JSON: " + e3Json);        
        IndexResponse indexResponse3 = client.prepareIndex("chat-data", "event", "3").setSource(e3Json).execute().actionGet();
        printIndexResponse("e3", indexResponse3);

        SearchRequestBuilder searchBuilder = client.prepareSearch();
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("value", "middle going");
        searchBuilder.setQuery(queryBuilder);

        CountRequestBuilder countBuilder = client.prepareCount();
        countBuilder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.constantScoreQuery(queryBuilder));

        CountResponse countResponse1 = countBuilder.execute().actionGet();
        System.out.println("HITS: " + countResponse1.getCount());

        SearchResponse searchResponse1 = searchBuilder.execute().actionGet();
        SearchHits hits = searchResponse1.getHits();
        for(int i=0; i<hits.hits().length; i++) {
            SearchHit hit = hits.getAt(i);
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + hit.getId() + " : " +hit.sourceAsString());
        }


        client.close();
    }

    private static void printIndexResponse(String description, IndexResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Index response for: " + description);
        System.out.println("Index name: " + response.getIndex());
        System.out.println("Index type: " + response.getType());
        System.out.println("Index id: " + response.getId());
        System.out.println("Index version: " + response.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jan 29, 2015 1:22:06 AM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [Diablo] loaded [], sites []
JSON: {"type":"LOGIN","date":1422474727304,"value":"Agent1 logged into chat"}
Index response for: e1
Index name: chat-data
Index type: event
Index id: 1
Index version: 184
JSON: {"type":"LOGOUT","date":1422474727360,"value":"Agent1 logged out of chat"}
Index response for: e2
Index name: chat-data
Index type: event
Index id: 2
Index version: 182
JSON: {"type":"BREAK","date":1422474727365,"value":"Agent1 went on break in the middle of a chat"}
Index response for: e3
Index name: chat-data
Index type: event
Index id: 3
Index version: 160
HITS: 1
[0] 3 : {"type":"BREAK","date":1422474716500,"value":"Agent1 went on break in the middle of a chat"}
```

Intermittent Output:

```
Jan 29, 2015 1:23:30 AM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [Mekano] loaded [], sites []
JSON: {"type":"LOGIN","date":1422474811618,"value":"Agent1 logged into chat"}
Index response for: e1
Index name: chat-data
Index type: event
Index id: 1
Index version: 222
JSON: {"type":"LOGOUT","date":1422474811671,"value":"Agent1 logged out of chat"}
Index response for: e2
Index name: chat-data
Index type: event
Index id: 2
Index version: 220
JSON: {"type":"BREAK","date":1422474811673,"value":"Agent1 went on break in the middle of a chat"}
Index response for: e3
Index name: chat-data
Index type: event
Index id: 3
Index version: 198
HITS: 0
```

What is the guarantee in elastic search w.r.t. search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticsearch provides near realtime search capabilities. Which means by default Elasticsearch takes some time until the indexed document is available for searching.

This process of making new documents available for searching is called index refresh. This is be default 1 second. Which means it will take a max of 1 second before the new documents indexed are available for searching. But remember , these documents are still retrievable using GET API , But not searchable using _Search API.

You can do the following to change this behavior -

1. [Apply refresh on the index](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) manually before search
2. While indexing , for the documents you want to make immediately searchable , [enable the refresh flag](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh)
3. Change the [default refresh interval](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)